# Chines language support showing empty result for zh

Tags: fonts, chinese

check-language-support -l zh    -> This command empty result on system ubuntu. what to do for getting language support for zh

check-language-support -l zh-hant  -> command list showing .

check-language-support -l zh-hans   -> command lists showing.

Answer (score 1):

To make things faster, I will post this in English, but let me know whether or not I should translate things in Chinese. 如果需要翻译， 请告诉我

According to man page,

> check-language-support  - returns the list of missing packages in
>          order to provide a complete language environment

It's purpose is to check for missing ( -l zh ) or installed (--show-installed) language packages. But you still should be able to download the language packages, even if this command does not work.

Bellow I will post output for what I have installed and what I have not installed on my system, according to this command. I have couple different desktop environments (gnome cinnamon, and kde), so you do not need all of these packages, just select what is necessary for you. Any ibus package is important , so feel free downloading that. I do not know whether reboot is needed after downloading, but I recommend doing so for changes to take effect.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Among other things I'd recommend getting `zhcon` package and `zh-autoconvert` package. You can find information about them by using `apt-cache search chinese` (which is what i did).

You should be able to do the very same thing I described here with Language support in system options. In fact, if some packages are missing, it should tell you, like it did to me when i opened it.

[image]
[image]